# how to double click on installed printer in devices and printers

Tags: python, windows, printers

i want to open installed printer in devices and printers.
 i used, 
start_application    control printers    Devices and Printers
to open the devices and printers. Now i want to double click on the installed printer. for example my printer name is Rose, i want to double on Rose icon and launch it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide some code, so we can help you? Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#controlling-the-mouse) library, additionally you can look of `subprocess` module.